# authentication controller on jhipster

Tags: spring, spring-security, social-networking, jhipster

I have generated jhipster using yo command (yo jhipster)

and selected session based authentication & support social sign-in

everything is working very well.

but I have a simple question.

where is the login controller to handle `"/api/authentication"` request (POST)

I can't find it.

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is configured in `SecurityConfiguration.java`, in the configure method.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http<% if (authenticationType == 'session') { %>
        .csrf()
        .ignoringAntMatchers("/websocket/**")
    .and()
        .addFilterAfter(new CsrfCookieGeneratorFilter(), CsrfFilter.class)<% } %>
        .exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)<% if (authenticationType == 'session') { %>
    .and()
        .rememberMe()
        .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
        .rememberMeParameter("remember-me")
        .key(env.getProperty("jhipster.security.rememberme.key"))
    .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginProcessingUrl("/api/authentication")
        .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password")
        .permitAll()
```

https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/blob/master/generators/server/templates/src/main/java/package/config/_SecurityConfiguration.java#L170